# Making o-bromoaniline from aniline

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

How can I make *o*-bromoaniline from aniline (as a major product)?

I know how to make *p*-bromoaniline from aniline, by acetylation followed by treatment with $\ce{Br2}$/$\ce{CH3COOH}$ and hydrolysis. But in this process the ortho isomer (if formed) will be the minor product.

Comment: Did you consider different sequences? Remember that aromatic nitro compounds can be reduced to the corresponding amines ;-)

Comment: @Klaus Warzecha But even if I consider nitro benzene, the ortho isomer will be the minor product. Would the yield be satisfactory ?

Comment: Remember how the nitro group directs. If you start with nitrobenzene, chances are good that the bromination will almost exclusively yield the *meta*-substituted product. But what if you try to nitrate bromobenzene?

Answer (score 8):

Didn't you consider the way through sulfanilic acid, the *para*-position will be protected. In this case both substituents will direct the electrophilic substitution in *ortho*- position with respect to amino group. Then remove sulfonic acid group by desulfonation and you will obtain your *ortho*-bromoaniline.

Comment: Wont it exist in zwitter ion form and loose its directing influence?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you probably cannot avoid separating ortho from para isomers (and possibly disubstitution products) after using a method like the one you suggest or a method of blocking the para- position.

Another method that is probably not taught to undergraduates (?) is the [Directed ortho metallation (DoM)](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/directed-ortho-metalation.shtm) or Snieckus chemistry. The image below has been copied from that link.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in a comment direct bromination of nitrobenzene with $\ce{Br2}$ and $\ce{FeBr3}$ is likely to give the *meta*-substituted product.

If you want to avoid time-consuming and expensive procedures, your options are:

- Change the order of events. Nitrate bromobenzene under mild(er) conditions, or
- Find conditions, under which bromination of nitrobenzene furnishes the *ortho*-product

For the latter, have a look at *Chem. Commun.*, **1996**, 2679-2680
([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/CC9960002679)). The authors state:

> We have observed that monosubstituted benzene derivatives
>   react with a mixture of dimethyl sulfoxide and aqueous
>   hydrobromic acid […] to yield regiospecifically only the
>   monobromo derivatives. It is interesting to note that electron-
>   withdrawing groups such as $\ce{NO2}$, $\ce{CHO}$ yield *ortho*-bromo
>   derivatives, while electron-donating groups such as $\ce{NH2}$, $\ce{OH}$ or $\ce{Me}$ give only *para*-bromo derivatives.